# Dynamically change row color in NatTable

Tags: java, nattable

I am trying to change the background row color based on the rows criteria. I am very close but there's something off I can't quite put my finger on. (I believe it's because I'm pulling an Object from an underlying list vs getting the data dynamically. I marked this section of the code below)

In the example below, each row color is based off of an Object (MyObj) which has a success or failure value.  If myObj has a success value the row should be green.  If myObj has a failure value the row should be red.  If myObj has no value, the default row color should be used.

When I run the code, the row colors display as expected.  However, if I sort the columns the original rows index maintains that color while the data moves to a new row index. I would expect that the row color would move with the object instead of always being fixed at that row index.

```
Example:
 Row 1 - "SUCCESS" - Shows Green
 Row 2 - "FAIL" - Shows Red
```

If I sort on that column alphabetically I get:

```
 Row 1 - "FAIL - Shows Green
 Row 2 - "SUCCESS" - Shows Red
```

Below is the code snippet I use to generate the example:

```
void example() {
    getNatTable().addConfiguration(new AbstractRegistryConfiguration() {
        @Override
        public void configureRegistry(IConfigRegistry configRegistry) {
            Style cellStyleSuccess = new Style();
            cellStyleSuccess.setAttributeValue(
                                CellStyleAttributes.BACKGROUND_COLOR,
                                COLOR_SUCCESS);
            configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(
                                CellConfigAttributes.CELL_STYLE, 
                                cellStyleSuccess,
                                DisplayMode.NORMAL, "SUCCESS");

            Style cellStyleFail = new Style();
            cellStyleFail.setAttributeValue(
                                CellStyleAttributes.BACKGROUND_COLOR, 
                                COLOR_FAILURE);
            configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(
                                CellConfigAttributes.CELL_STYLE, 
                                cellStyleFail,
                                DisplayMode.NORMAL, "FAIL");
        }
    });
    DataLayer dl = getGlazedListsGridLayer().getBodyDataLayer();
    IConfigLabelAccumulator cellLabelAccumulator = 
      new IConfigLabelAccumulator() {
        @Override
        public void accumulateConfigLabels(LabelStack configLabels, 
                        int columnPosition, int rowPosition) {
            configLabels.getLabels().clear();
            // TODO Is this the issue? Is there a better way to 
            // pull MyObj here?
            MyObj myObj = getEventList().get(rowPosition);
            if (myObj.getFoo().equals("SUCCESS")) {
                configLabels.addLabel("SUCCESS");
            } else if (myObj.getFoo().equals("FAIL"))) {
                configLabels.addLabel("FAIL");
            } else {
                // default color
            }

        }
    };

    dl.setConfigLabelAccumulator(cellLabelAccumulator);
    getNatTable().configure();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important part that probably causes the issue is missing. Which list is returned by `getEventList()`? If it is the basic `EventList` you always get the object at the original index. When you sort a transformation is applied via `SortedList`. So your issue should be solved if `getEventList()` returns the top most GlazedLists collection (`SortedList` or `FilterList` dependent on which features you are using).

Comment: yeah I am using an EventList. I'll have to do what you said. Thanks!

Comment: FYI I used:
MyObj myObj = getGlazedListsGridLayer().getBodyDataProvider().getRowObject(rowPosition);